# Difference between word sense discovery and word sense induction?

Tags: nlp

What is the difference between word sense discovery and word sense induction.
I have checked [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word-sense_induction) Wikipedia page.It says that its strictly related to WSD.
So what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this book](http://ethesis.helsinki.fi/julkaisut/hum/yleis/vk/linden/wordsens.pdf) of K. Linden. 
"Word sense discovery is defined as the task of learning what senses a word may have in different contexts.
[...] this task can be seen as consisting of three steps. The first step is to determine the groups of related words in context, i.e., create a context clustering. [...]
The second step is to determine a suitable inventory of word sense labels. [...]
the third step involves a way to learn how to associate a word sense label with a word cluster"

So, word sense discovery is a more general task than word sense induction.